# Android SQLite: Creating and updating rows from database

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been using https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper library for pre-populated database in app. When I want to update multiple rows, the documentation said I should write sql script for that. Is there any other way for that because there are around 200+ rows I want to update. I can't replace the database with new one also because there're already user data in other tables in it.

Comment: What kind of data rows you are updating?

Answer (score 0):

**In short no, SQL is how you interact with the database.**

However one single UPDATE could update every row.

Additionally there are convenience methods such as the update method that builds the SQL.

For example say you had a table named **mytable** which had a column called **name** and you wanted to change all occurrences of **joe** to **Joseph** then the SQL could be :-

```
String sql = "UPDATE mytable SET name = 'Joseph' WHERE name = 'joe'";
```

Now assuming that you had a an SQLiteDatabase instance named **db** then you could use :-

```
db.execSQL(sql);
```

Alternately you could use :-

```
String wherecluase = "name =?";
String[] whereargs = new String[]{"joe"};
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("name","Joseph");
int rows_updated = db.update("mytable",cv,whereclause,whereargs);
```

- This builds and executes the SQL as above.
- This may seem to be more long-winded however there are advantages to using this method e.g.

  - it returns the number of rows that were updated,
  - it offfers protecting against SQL injection,
  - it properly encloses/escapes data
  - the SQL will be syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Its one way, but not the only way.  Another good way is to send them the new data in a new database.  Then after you download it, copy the data from the new database to the old one, using upsert mechanics.  That would update data to the new information, without losing rows inserted by the user.  Of course if you need to worry about changes made by the user, then you need to find some way to detect that and do conflict resolution.